# CakePHP 2.9 $this->Auth->user('id') is null

Tags: php, routes, cakephp

I'm having an issue where my CakePHP application is not retrieving any user data. It's authenticating me, but then there's no ID value whatsoever.

After careful checking of the docs, I realize the problem is `$this->Auth->user('id');` is null, despite being logged in. Interesting. Does anyone know why it would be?

I've checked everything I can think of, even included the fields in the `AppController.php`, I'm not sure how to fix this. Session is started, and valid, just the information isn't being pulled.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was because the person that made it had a `register.js` file that was triggering before the form submit so it was sending the data instead of CakePHP so it was never actually authenticating normally, it was manual before